# Kurento Media Server 6.4 - Runtime check failed error in log

Tags: kurento

I'm using Kurento Media Server 6.4 and I've been getting a bunch of errors like this in my error log:

```
(kurento-media-server:6835): libnice-WARNING **: (agent.c:2156):agent_signal_component_state_change: runtime check failed: (TRANSITION (DISCONNECTED, FAILED) || TRANSITION (GATHERING, FAILED) || TRANSITION (CONNECTING, FAILED) || TRANSITION (CONNECTED, FAILED) || TRANSITION (READY, FAILED) || TRANSITION (DISCONNECTED, GATHERING) || TRANSITION (GATHERING, CONNECTING) || ...
```

Is there any insight as to what's causing them?

Comment: Hi, was my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't affect you. It's a problem in libnice that is not expecting the state change that is taking place. It's just a warning for libnice developers. The connection should be established correctly, so you can safely ignore this.